# Change lockscreen in MATE?

Tags: lightdm, lock-screen, mate

I want the `lightdm-webkit-greeter` to be mine lockscreen, do you know how to change it? I found a way how to add Xscreensaver screensavers to `mate-screensaver` or even change background, but no word on how to change lockscreen completely.

EDIT: Just to make it clear: I use `lightdm-webkit-greeter` for login and it works, but when I close the lid, the `mate-screensaver-command -l` is executed - which I want to change it to `lightdm-webkit-greeter` aswell using `dm-tool lock`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's a correct way, but yes, I sort of figured this out. I Disabled the MATE's lockscreen in screensaver settings and added `light-locker --lock-on-suspend --late-locking --lock-after-screensaver=30` startup command.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `lightdm` you just have to install it: `sudo apt-get install lightdm`. During the install, you'll be asked to select your default display manager. Select `lightdm`.

If `lightdm` is already installed, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.

Comment: Well the `lightdm` was pre-installed and I even managed to get `lightd-webkit-greeter` to work at system start. So do I have to reinstall lightdm to get the lockscreen changing dialogue?

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Comment: That seems like it's doing nothing. The command doesn't show error, warning or any message at all. I tried it with `lightdm` stopped. EDIT: even `sudo apt-get --reinstall install lightdm` does not offer such dialogue.

Comment: Try it with `gdm` instead.

Comment: Are you sure you have `lightdm` installed?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that `lightdm` is installed and running and that `gdm` is not installed at all. EDIT: I made it cleare in the question that I just want to switch the lockscreen only when the pc (laptop)  is suspended.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The lockscreen and login screen are essentially the same thing.

Comment: That's what I thought, but  they clearly aren't.

Comment: You have a default display manager. You can't use both at the same time. It's even said in the installation of a display manager.

Comment: Umm ... do I? I do have only `lightdm` installed, no `gdm`, no `nodm`, no `xdm`, no `sddm`, no `wdm` not even a `lxdm`. So I believe that I am using only one display manager at the time, and I don't think that it's even possible to run two simultaneously.

Comment: I don't want to seem rude and I thank you for your time, but I don't want to change my display manager, I just want to change the command that locks the screen when I close my laptop lid, since I can't find it by myself. Right now, the system seems to call `mate-lockscreen-command -l` and I just want it change it to `dm-tool lock`.